# Rerender component from different component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

In component A I have a function that adds a object to my localforage:

```
localforage.setItem('trackedMovies', value)
```

In component B I map through the `trackedMovies` array that I grab from localforage:

```
getData = async () => {
  const trackedMovies = await localforage.getItem<[]>('trackedMovies'); 

  this.setState({
    data: trackedMovies
  })
}

componentDidMount = () => {
  this.getData()
}

render() {
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <h1>Dashboard</h1>
      { this.state.data.map(movie => {
        return (
          <span key={movie.id}>{movie.original_title}</span>
        )
      })}
    </React.Fragment>
  )
}
```

Initially this works fine. But if I add new objects in the `trackedMovies` array component B does not update so I have to manually refresh the page to see the newly added object.

How do I rerender component B to show the results in the updated `trackedMovies` array?

Answer (score 0):

Try maintaining the elements of the `localStorage` in a `state`. So whenever you add an item in component A, add it to the `state` as well. Then you can pass it to B.

Comment: Isn't state bound to it's component?

Comment: It is defined in the constructor but you can pass the whole state object as a prop.
`<Component B itemsInLocalStorage={this.state.itemsInLocalStorage} />`. Then in `Component B`, you can acess these props using `this.props.itemsInLocalStorage`. Instead of `this.state.data.map`, you will have to use `this.props.itemsInLocalStorage.map`.